# How to Change title text-color in Preference Category

Tags: android, android-preferences

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Login email">
    <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="display_email"
        android:title="test email"/>
</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/server_settings_title">
    <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="Server_Select"
        android:summary="@string/server_select_summary"
        android:title="@string/server_pref"/>
</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/settings_title">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:id="@+id/enter_send"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="@string/settings_enterPreference_key"
        android:summary="@string/settings_enterPreference_summary"
        android:title="@string/settings_enterPreference_label" />
</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/settings_mic">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:id="@+id/mic_input"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="@string/setting_mic_key"
        android:summary="@string/settings_micPreference_summary"
        android:title="@string/setting_mic_input" />

    <SwitchPreference
        android:id="@+id/hotword_detection"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="@string/setting_hotword_key"
        android:summary="@string/settings_hotwordPreference_summary"
        android:title="@string/setting_hotword_detection" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

I want to change the text-color of the Category and not screen. I have referred to many docs and blog posts regarding this but in vain. This is part of a large code base and hence I want to be careful

Answer (score 0):

Create a class which extends PreferenceCategory.

```
public class CustomPreferenceCategory extends PreferenceCategory {

@TargetApi(21)
public CustomPreferenceCategory(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    this.init(context, attrs);
}

public CustomPreferenceCategory(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.init(context, attrs);
}

public CustomPreferenceCategory(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.init(context, attrs);
}

public CustomPreferenceCategory(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.init(context, (AttributeSet)null);
}

public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
    TextView title = (TextView)holder.itemView;
    title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
}
private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this.setLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_category);
}
```

Then replace PreferenceCategory with name of custom class in xml like this:

```
<mypackage.CustomPreferenceCategory android:title="Login email">
```

Comment: onBinViewHolder shows an error and asks to rename reference

Comment: Can you share log ?