# How to Change SwitchPreference text color when switch is enabled?

Tags: android, switchpreference

[See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pquaz.png)

I want to change that text color of 'Enabled' to blue

Here is my xml

```
<SwitchPreference
android:defaultValue="false"
android:key="startScan"
android:summaryOff="@string/prefs_scan_startup_summary"
android:summaryOn="Enabled"
android:title="@string/prefs_scan_startup" />
```

Comment: it's not here, you have to do something with the app theme color etc

Comment: Thank you. Will let know what works out best.

Answer (score 1):

Well... if noone else knows of a easy solution it might be tricky.

In general you could create a Sharedpreference listener that would update whatever property you want when the Switch state (and thus the SharedPreference) changes.

However I can't see a way to specifically change the textcolor of a SwitchPreference, so you might have to extend the SwitchPreference class and use your custom view where you would have access to the actual TextView to change its color.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950228/7968986) for reference on extending that custom class.

Comment: Yes, I believe that’s the only way. Will let know what turns out best. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, if it works out in the end please mark this answer as the solution otherwise let me know what doesn't work